# ReactJs TypeScript : Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ;

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some trouble with my code.

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface SearchProductSate {
  [key: string]: string;
  Id: string;
  Name: string;
  Section: string;
  Domaine: string;
  IsActive: string;
}

export class SearchProductComponent extends React.Component<
  SearchProductProps,
  SearchProductSate
> {
    constructor(props: SearchProductProps) {
      super(props);
    }

  handleSelectChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    var safeSearchTypeValue: string = event.currentTarget.value;
    const name = event.currentTarget.name;

    const o = {} as SearchProductSate;
    o[name] = safeSearchTypeValue;

    this.setState(o);
  }
...
}
```

In VsCode, I don't have any warning or error. When, I run 'npm run build', everything is ok, but when I run 'npm start', that's the mess ;o).

I obtain this error message :

```
Syntax error: ./SearchProductComponent.tsx: Unexpected token, expected ; (55:17)

  53 |     const name = event.currentTarget.name;
  54 | 
> 55 |     const o = {} as SearchProductSate;
     |                  ^
  56 |     o[name] = safeSearchTypeValue;
  57 | 
  58 |     this.setState(o);
```

If I comment the cast, the component work but in VsCode, I have an error on 'o[name] = safeSearchTypeValue;'

```
L'élément a implicitement un type 'any', car le type '{}' n'a aucune signature d'index.
```

that I could translate by

```
The element was type 'any', because the type '{}' doesn't have any index signature
```

How to fix this issue and how to manage to avoid same problem in the futur ?

Comment: That syntax error doesn't look like a TypeScript error message.  Are you using some other tool?  Please add your `package.json` to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My package.json is http://paste.alacon.org/45391

Comment: Please post your scripts/start.js and any relevant configuration files (e.g., Webpack or Babel configuration) so we can see what tool you are using that is having trouble with the TypeScript syntax.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

We find why we have these some mistake. We use VsCode which automaticly validate in typescript our code but webpack was configure to use babel-loader.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface states that the following fields must exist on the object Id, Name, Section, etc.

Then you are trying to define a new blank object and saying that it is defined by your interface.

If you either added the required fields to the empty object you are setting up:

```
 const o = {
      Id: '',
      Name: '',
      Section: '',
      etc...
 } as SearchProductSate;
```

OR define your interface with optional fields

```
 export interface SearchProductSate {
     [key: string]?: string;
     Id?: string;
     Name?: string;
     Section?: string;
     Domaine?: string;
     IsActive?: string;
 }
```